# What are the options for fellowships for international grad students in USA?

Tags: graduate-school, phd, funding

I'm looking for fellowships that an international grad student can apply for, to support him/her while working towards a Ph.D. (additional to whatever funding that may be available as TA). So far, I've been able to identify the following:

- [Fulbright Scholarships for International Students](http://scienceandtech.fulbrightonline.org/eligibility) (applications have to be done more than a year before, and they've suspended 2013-14 grants, so not really an option for me)
- [Aga Khan Foundation International Scholarship Programme](http://www.akdn.org/akf_scholarships.asp), which has the following selection criteria:

> The main criteria for selecting award winners are: l) excellent academic records, 2) genuine financial need, 3) admission to a reputable institution of higher learning and 4) thoughtful and coherent educational and career plans. Candidates are also evaluated on their extra-curricular interests and achievements, potential to achieve their goals and likelihood to succeed in a foreign academic environment. Applicants are expected to have some years of work experience in their field of interest.

It would be great if I could get to know of similar fellowships that an incoming student can apply to, *before* starting grad school.

Comment: This is a list type question. It has been frowned upon in other SEs. Is this within scope?

Comment: According to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia/17096#17096, questions about student loans/grants are not off-topic, as long as its specific - which I believe this question is...

Comment: `Where can I find information` is somewhat different from  `Can you list all information`. Eitherways, I am no one to decide. I too hope it is within scope.

Comment: I'm asking for "where can I find *more* information" than the one's I've listed... which I hope is within the scope of this SE!

Comment: I would recommend reformulating the question to remove the discipline-specificity from your question. Otherwise you could have a separate such question in every academic field, which we probably want to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Smithsonian [offers fellowships for international grad students](http://www.si.edu/ofg/fell.htm), specifically a ten-week summer internship for pre-dissertation grad students and 3-12 months of funding for post-dissertation grad students. Also, you get to work at the Smithsonian.